# jQuery mobile panel with unwanted margin top

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

My goal is to create a pannel on the right with jQuery Mobile 1.4.5 where the pannel holds links within a listview. The pannel should open with a click on a "burger menu icon"

Somehow the pannel has an unwanted margin and the button should be an icon, instead it is a simple link:

[image]

The code for the link:

```
<a href="#right-panel" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="false">Menu</a>
```

What could be the reason for this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a problem of the jQuery docs and examples:

1. The jQuery examples are missing `data-role="button"` which each link needs if it should show up as a button
2. there is a margin of the menu, which I simply removed by adding `margin:0px;`
3. copy&pasting the code from the examples has   elements within that one can not see. Remove all spaces and add them again